# Warning: NavController.setNavigatorProvider can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.navigation)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a new project and met with this warning while setting up bottom-tab navigation.

**Gradle info**

- AndroidStudio: 4.1.2
- compileSdkVersion: 29
- Navigation dependencies:

  - implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1"
  - implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1"

**My Code:**

```
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)?.let {
        val navigator = KeepStateNavigator(
            this,
            it.childFragmentManager,
            R.id.nav_host_fragment
        )

        // This line gives me warning
        navController.navigatorProvider += navigator
      
    }
}
```

**Tried solution:**

```
// Solution 1
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {


// Solution 2
// noinspection RestrictedApi
navController.navigatorProvider += navigator
```

Both are worked but I still don't know why I am getting this error. Is there anything anything else that I should know that might create the problem in future?

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might avoid warning using the below code:

```
navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(navigator)
```